# Button is not reacting as expected, I am trying to see if the function is not working or if there some other error

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, math, button

The function should use user input to do math and output into a text box for the user. On clicking the button, absolutely nothing happens. LogCat isn't showing me anything, so I'm not sure how to Troubleshoot this issue. I've got two similiar activities in the same project that are working fine, so I suspect I may not being doing the math correctly but can't find any other information. Any advice is appreciated.

```
package com.example.awcc
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main3.*

class Setup : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    editTextNumber120.text.toString().toInt()
 }
}

class ThirdActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)

    val button2 = findViewById< Button >(R.id.button2)
    button2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    val button3 = findViewById< Button >(R.id.button3)
    button3.setOnClickListener {
        val intent2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent2)

        val button7 = findViewById< Button >(R.id.button35)
        button7.setOnClickListener {
                var value1 = editTextNumber120.text.toString().toInt()

                fun accessory(): Int {

                    return when {

                        value1 > 10 -> value1 * 0

                        value1 in 10..20 -> value1 * 1

                        value1 in 21..40 -> value1 * 2

                        value1 in 40..50 -> value1 * 3

                        value1 in 51..75 -> value1 * 4

                        value1 < 75 -> value1 * 5

                        else -> value1
                    }
                }

                val complete = accessory().toString()
                try {
                    editTextNumber19?.setText(complete)
                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Please enter a 0 in the blank field",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you're putting the `button7.setOnClickListener` inside `button3.setOnClickListener` ??

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Good catch! I've fixed that but still get nothing when clicking the button. Is it simply an issue of math? I believe it's programmed properly but could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

where is `editTextNumber120` defined? what is this text being used for?

If you're expecting the value to carry over from the setup activity to activity3, that's not how it works.  Each activity uses it's own data and if you need data to be shared across Activities and Fragments, then you need to create a data model for that information.

Example:

```
public class MyDataModel {
    protected MutableLiveData<Int> editTextData;

    public MyDataModel() {
        editTextData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    // setter/getter - returns a LiveData object that allows
    //     you to observe the value for any changes
    // If you don't need to observe changes, then just keep it as an int/string

}
```

This way your other Activity can access the same data being used in the Setup activity. Also note, this doesn't persist across reboots, so if you want the setup to contain the previous data used in the last boot of the app, i'd look into `SharedPreferences`.

Also I don't know the structure of your app, but I would question why you need so many Activities? My app I'm working on is fairly robust but even I only have one activity (with a couple fragments), and another activity for the settings, and that's it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! As far as the structure with three activities, each page has different input boxes (We have three different forms of commission payout) so you can swap between them depending on which one you are trying to calculate. That may not be the most efficient way (I'm new, this is my first update to my first app.) 

Regarding edittextnumber120, I need to remove that as I was using it as a test earlier in development and forgot to remove it... I should really get better at clean code.

And thanks for the tip on SharedPreferences because that was my next planned update

Comment: so they didn't have to re-enter it every time! I actually ended up solving the issue I had shortly after reading your comment. Because I was using var instead of val it wasn't properly handling the math!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer if anyone runs into this issue behind me. I was using Var instead of Val so it wasn't actually multiplying or changing the var at all. Changed to Val and it works like a charm!